# Date value not storing in database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using `Codeigniter` with `Grocery Crud`, to connect with a database in `MySQL` and `PhpMyAdmin`.

I installed everything as the tutorial said, but errors can always be there.

My problem is: I have a simple table (3 fields, one for name, another one for last name and another one for date of birth), using `varchar (255)` for the first two, and `DATE` for the date of birth. When I add a new record, or update an existing one, it says it successfully did the job, but it actually didn't. And ONLY with the `DATE` field. I can perfectly add and update the other 2 columns.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I added the code as asked for. This is the `Controller` that gets the patients:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class GetPatients extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "<h1>Welcome to the world of Codeigniter</h1>"; //Just an example to ensure that we get into the function
        die();
    }

    public function dbpatients()
    {
        $this->grocery_crud->set_table('patient');
        $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
    }

    function _example_output($output = null)
    {
        $this->load->view('patients_view',$output);
    }

}
```

Comment: can u post the example of your code..?

Comment: @AminAdha sure, let me edit the question.

Comment: @AminAdha If you need anything else just let me know.

Comment: are u using the right date format for mysql?

Comment: @AminAdha The date format for MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD ... And I set my GroceryCrud php file to use this format.

Comment: i use the same setting for my column dob.. n i have no problem with it.. try to echo the mysql error or check the dob column setting in phpmyadmin (esp EXTRA cloumn in table structure tab)

Comment: @AminAdha How do I do this?

Comment: @AminAdha I know conversations this long can't be held in comments section so please talk to me by mail at jeancarlos255@gmail.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42153/discussion-between-amin-adha-and-jean-carlos-suarez-marranzini)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql date col only supports numbers or string as assignment values.
you can convert your date format

```
$datestring = "%Y%m%d";
    $time = time();
    $date = mdate($datestring, $time);
```